# JavaFX: How to get all rows in TableView

Tags: javafx, javafx-tableview

I'd like to know the best & most efficient way to get JavaFX TableView data to a collection. I want to get all rows inside a JavaFX TableView.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Evin! Don't be too discouraged by downvotes. Upvotes and downvotes are part of our system to determine the usefulness of a question for future users. Because this answer is easily found in the documentation for TableView, the question received some downvotes since Java's official documentation would be a better place for future users to find the answer than stackoverflow would.

Comment: There are actually two questions being asked: - the "`TableView` data to a collection." and - "I want to get all rows inside a JavaFX `TableView`.", probably referring to actual `TableRow` instances. `getItems()` only answers the first question since it returns the actual data model, not the `TableRow`s. For the second question all I could find on a quickish search was [here, using `tableView.lookupAll(".table-row-cell");`](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=javafx.scene.control.TableCell).
However that call returned an empty list when I tested it locally. Right now I have tro

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`getItems()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getItems--) call you can make to get the contents of a `TableView`. It returns an `ObservableList` which is a type of `Collection`.